# app_identity_service.GetAccessToken() required more quota than is available

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-authentication, google-oauth

I am using app engine and big query as the backend for my website. Whenever the user does some click, i log them into bigquery to do analytics later in the day. I get close to 75k clicks a day. It was working fine till last week. This is the code i use.

```
    body = {"rows":[bodyFields]}

    credentials = appengine.AppAssertionCredentials(scope=BIGQUERY_SCOPE)
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    bigquery = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)

    response = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(
        projectId=PROJECT_ID,
        datasetId=BIGQUERY_DATASETID,
        tableId=BIGQUERY_TABLEID,
        body=body).execute()
```

Now all of a sudden i am getting over quota exception. My application is a paid app engine instance. Below is the stack-trace of my exception

[image: dashboard screenshot]

```
Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token

The API call app_identity_service.GetAccessToken() required more quota than is available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~projectname/bigqueryapi.387952303347375306/filename.py", line 1611, in post
    bigquery = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~projectname/bigqueryapi.387952303347375306/oauth2client/util.py", line 129, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~projectname/bigqueryapi.387952303347375306/apiclient/discovery.py", line 198, in build
    resp, content = http.request(requested_url)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~projectname/bigqueryapi.387952303347375306/oauth2client/util.py", line 129, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~projectname/bigqueryapi.387952303347375306/oauth2client/client.py", line 516, in new_request
    self._refresh(request_orig)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~projectname/bigqueryapi.387952303347375306/oauth2client/appengine.py", line 194, in _refresh
    scopes, service_account_id=self.service_account_id)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/app_identity/app_identity.py", line 589, in get_access_token
    scopes, service_account_id=service_account_id)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/app_identity/app_identity.py", line 547, in get_access_token_uncached
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/app_identity/app_identity.py", line 519, in get_access_token_result
    rpc.check_success()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 579, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 134, in CheckSuccess
    raise self.exception
OverQuotaError: The API call app_identity_service.GetAccessToken() required more quota than is available.
```

My traffic hasn't gone up by much also the number of time the handler is hit is almost the same as past 2 months data. So why am i getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

In order to determine why you're hitting the quota error, you'll need to share more detail about your usage.  The quota should reset every 24 hours. Do you know how long it takes for the error to appear and how much traffic you've successfully served to that point in time?

You mentioned that you "do analytics later in the day", which suggests that you might be using the [TaskQueue API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) or [Deferred Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred?hl=en). It's possible that those tasks are failing for other reasons and [retrying](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/taskretryoptions), which could quickly eat up your quota. If you are using TaskQueues, you might try tuning the [queue configuration and retry options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue).

Another way you might be able to conserve your quota would be to save the `bigquery` discovery service that you're building to something like the Memcache API, so that it can be reused for multiple requests to the BigQuery service.

Comment: I use ton of TaskQueue for calling functions which I do not want to block time on for the user. Does task queue eat up access_token quota ?

Comment: I also felt the problem was with discovery service. So i re-wrote my code to use the REST api endpoint of bigQuery. still the issue persists. Also according to my understanding, the app engine API handles the caching of access_token by default

Comment: TaskQueue usage alone won't affect your `access_token` quota and there's nothing wrong with using the TaskQueue. The `access_token` might be cached, but it's likely that it's cached per request and every Task runs in a separate request.

Do you have statistics you can share on how many tasks you run per day and how many run successfully?